# Calling UIKit method from Xamarin Binding

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uikit

I have an advertisement SDK binding for my Xamarin Project. The binding is here: https://github.com/bbhsu2/XamarinAdMarvelBinding

My problem comes from the method:

```
[Export("adMarvelViewFrame")]
RectangleF AdMarvelViewFrame();
```

in my class I implement it as such:

```
[Export("adMarvelViewFrame")]
public RectangleF AdMarvelViewFrame()
{
    return new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 250.0f);
}
```

however, when the view loads, I get the error:

```
UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
```

I (think) I understand what this error means, but how would I invoke it on the main thread when it's called elsewhere by native code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIKIt method you're calling is UIScreen.MainScreen.

The easy fix is to pre-fetch UIScreen.MainScreen in a class variable, and use the class variable in your AdMarvelViewFrame.